# ChartJS: chart not show all data

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

For some reason, this chart not show the last two data from the array.

```
var data = {
    labels: ["Brasil", "Argentina", "Chile", "Paraguai", "Peru", "Bolívia", "México"],
    datasets: [{
        data: [ 9.19, 7.77, 6.80, 6.23, 6.00, 4.00, 4.00 ],
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor
    }],
};
```

http://codepen.io/marcelo2605/pen/PWWqJm?editors=0010

Anyone known why is this happens?

Comment: It does not show it because the y axis starts at 4 which right from the bottom. You can see it, if you set:
`xAxes: [{
   display: true
  }]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to set Y-Axis to start with 0, by default it start with the minimum value present in the data set which is 4 in your case. Due to this last 2 columns with value 4 are not visible.

```
 yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
```

updated Pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxxVBp?editors=0010

Comment: Nice! I thought the default was zero.

Answer (score 0):

The y-scale on your graph has a minimum of 4.
The value of your last 2 points is 4, so they are not shown.
Set the min to 0, or at least less than 4 and they will show.