# ChartJS: Chart not displaying full range of data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My ChartJS chart is not displaying all the data.  This is the [**closest question on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721481/chartjs-chart-not-show-all-data) to my problem.  Implementing the answer to this question did not help (I tried both `[{display: false}]` and `[{display: true}]`).

I am a novice at chartjs having only started working with it some ~5 days ago.  Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Basically, I am writing a chart that takes data collected by a Raspberry Pi and plots it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Harp comfort</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Temperature data</h1>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

    <script>
      // Data from: Raspberry Pi Hat     

      window.addEventListener('load', setup);      
      var ops = {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: false
                  }],
                yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                               }
                       }]
               }
              };
      async function setup() {
        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        const dataTemp = await getData();
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {            
            datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Temperature',
                data: dataTemp.temp,        
                fill: false,
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.85)',
                borderWidth: 2
              }              
            ]
          },
         options: ops
        });
      }

      async function getData() {        
        const response = await fetch('./sample.csv');
        const data = await response.text();        
        const temp = [];        
        const rows = data.split('\n').slice(1);
        rows.forEach(row => {
          const col = row.split(',');          
          temp.push(parseFloat(col[0]))
          //console.log(col[0]) //for debugging purpose
        });
        return { temp };
      }
      //getData(); for debugging purpose
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSV data (**sample.csv**) is available via this [PasteBin page](https://pastebin.com/smz69iNu)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.

I was able to solve this problem by ensuring that the CSV data had 2 columns. A single column of data does not work.  A two column data file ([PasteBin Link](https://pastebin.com/12rBzDSt)) along with the modified code works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Harp Temperature and RH</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Harp comfort</h1>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>



    <script>
      // Data from: Raspberry Pi Hat     

      window.addEventListener('load', setup);      
      var ops = {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: false
                  }],
                yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                               }
                       }]
               }
              };
      async function setup() {
        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        const dataTemp = await getData();
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {   
        labels: dataTemp.timestamp,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Temperature',
                data: dataTemp.temp,        
                fill: false,
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.85)',
                borderWidth: 2
              }              
            ]
          },
         options: ops
        });
      }

      async function getData() {        
        const response = await fetch('./sample.csv');
        const data = await response.text();     
    const timestamp = [];
        const temp = [];        
        const rows = data.split('\n').slice(1);
        rows.forEach(row => {
          const col = row.split(',');
      timestamp.push(col[0])
          temp.push(parseFloat(col[1]))
          //console.log(col[0]) //for debugging purpose
        });
        return { temp, timestamp };
      }
      //getData(); for debugging purpose
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

I would love it if more refined answers (than my novice solution!) be posted.